# String to UTF8 Char Conversion in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, utf-8, char

I'm trying to save an UTF8 char to a string and print it to a label.

If I hard code it works fine:

```
NSString *param = @"\uf02e";
NSLog(param);
```

Result:

```
2012-10-24 16:09:56.522 i[22996:12c03] 
```

By the way if I'm saving the char to a string I can't go back.

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[item objectForKey:content]];
NSLog(myString);
```

Result:

```
2012-10-24 16:18:47.289 i[23105:12c03] \uf02e
```

Any solution for this? Thanks.

EDIT

item is an NSDictionary and [item objectForKey:content] is a string.

[image]

Comment: How do you fill [item] array?

Comment: item is an NSDictionary filled with objects from a plist file.

Comment: So in your plist string is actually the string "\uf02e" itself, not the corresponding unicode character. Modifier \u doesn't work inside of strings inside of plist.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *param = @"\uf02e";
    NSDictionary* item = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: param forKey: @"key"];
    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[item objectForKey: @"key"]];
    NSLog(myString);
```

Works fine for me. So the error is in the value, that you're inserting into the dictionary.

Comment: I have attached an image. The value is saved correctly on the plist file as String. Your solution works but not with my code.

Comment: how do you load it from plist ?

Comment: +1 @CarloS The value you have stored in the dictionary looks like the string "\uf02e" (i.e. the escape sequence you'd supply to the compiler).  This won't work when the string is loaded like this as the compiler won't interpret the escape characters this way.  In fact the compiler won't see the string at all, will it.

Comment: It's quite complex to paste all the code. By the way myString is a string, same as param. Can't understand why they are treated differently.

Comment: Any way to convert "\uf02e" to \uf02e ? Cause I can't change the way I'm filling the dictionary.

Comment: @CarloS because the compiler isn't seeing the string!  The `\uXXXX` is a directive to the compiler to generate a UNICODE character.  What you are loading is a string '\', 'u', etc.

Comment: All right. I understand. So do you think there is a way to save a UNICODE character as a string in a plist file and restore it or not?

Comment: Yes - when editing the file insert the character (or perhaps use the Edit -> Insert Special menu - or whatever it's called).

Comment: You are right. I've tried to copy and paste the symbol instead of the corresponding UTF8 code and it works. Thanks.